# SQL Server 2008, Attendance Sheet

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

Table Employee:

```
EmpID | EmpName
1     |'Mr. A'
2     |'Mr. B'
```

Table OffDays:

```
OffDayID | OffDayName | OffDayValue
1        | 'Saturday' | 7
2        | 'Sunday'   | 1
```

Table Attendance:

```
AttendanceID | Date         | EmpID
1            | '2014-06-02' | 1
2            | '2014-06-03' | 1
3            | '2014-06-04' | 1
4            | '2014-06-05' | 1
5            | '2014-06-10' | 1
```

Employee 'Mr. A' with ID 1 is absent on '2014-06-06' Friday and '2014-06-09' Monday.
How to right query to show the holidays '0214-06-07', Saturday and '2014-06-8' Sunday between Absents as Absent.

Please help.

My stored procedure is

```
DECLARE @DATE_FROM AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DATE_TO AS DATETIME
SET @DATE_FROM = '2014-05-01'
SET @DATE_TO = '2014-05-31'

DECLARE @DATE_FROM2 AS DATETIME  
DECLARE @DATE_TO2 AS DATETIME  

SET @DATE_FROM2 = @DATE_FROM  
SET @DATE_TO2 = @DATE_TO  

TRUNCATE TABLE AttendanceRegister                      

--------------------Present,Absent,Leave-----------------------  
WHILE @DATE_FROM <= @DATE_TO                    
BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO AttendanceRegister  
 SELECT E.EmployeeID,                    
    @DATE_FROM,  
 CASE                                          
  WHEN A.AttendanceID IS NULL  OR A.TimeIn IS NULL                                        
  THEN  
   CASE  
    WHEN @DATE_FROM IN                                          
    (                                        
     SELECT CONVERT(DATE,LeaveDate)                                      
     FROM LeaveDetail  
     WHERE EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID                                      
    )  
    THEN 'L'  
    ELSE 'A'  
   END  
  ELSE 'P'  
 END  
 FROM Employee E                    
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance A ON A.[DayofMonth] = @DATE_FROM                    
 AND A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND A.IS_DELETED = 0        
 WHERE E.IS_DELETED  = 0 AND E.IS_ACTIVE = 1  
 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@DATE_FROM)
 NOT IN (  
 SELECT OffDayValue  
 FROM OffDays 
 )  
 SET @DATE_FROM = DATEADD(D,1,@DATE_FROM)                    
END   
-------------------------Holidays------------------------------  
WHILE @DATE_FROM2 <= @DATE_TO2  
BEGIN          
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@DATE_FROM2)
IN (  
SELECT OffDayValue  
FROM OffDays  
)  
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO AttendanceRegister                         
SELECT E.EmployeeID, @DATE_FROM2,'H'  
FROM Employee E  
WHERE E.IS_DELETED = 0 AND E.IS_ACTIVE = 1  
END  
SET @DATE_FROM2 = DATEADD(D,1,@DATE_FROM2)                    
END  
---------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT *
FROM AttendanceRegister
```

Comment: Put the data in tabular format, so that it's easy to understand the problem statement.

Comment: Sir I just need to show Absent On Sunday and Saturday when an employee is absent on Friday and Monday.

Comment: How you save the data which indicates that the employee was absent?

Comment: I have posted my code. Please have a look. Its working fine. But new requirement is Holidays should be treated as Absent if they occur between Consecutive Absents.